# Proof of the ratio increased and decreased theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, ratio

Let $$\frac{a}{b}$$ be a fraction.
Suppose I decrease the numerator and the denominator both by the same number.
$$\frac{a-x}{b-x}$$
Then, $$\tag{Equation 1}
\frac{a}{b}-\frac{a-x}{b-x}=\frac{x}{b}\frac{b-a}{b-x}$$
If $$a>b$$
Then,

> ***Equation 1 is negative***

This implies
$$\tag{Inequality 1}
\frac{a}{b}<\frac{a-x}{b-x}$$
But from previous question, here on this site , I got to know that equation 1 is not necessarily negative.

I read this proof but I think it is only true if $$a>b>x>0$$ So how can we prove that $$\frac{a}{b}<\frac{a-x}{b-x}$$if $$a>b$$

Comment: "*how can we prove*" $\;-\;$ Prove what exactly? $\,3 \gt 2\,$ but $\,\dfrac{3}{2} \not\gt \dfrac{3-1}{2-1}\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Oh, $$\frac{3}{2}>\frac{3-1}{2-1}$$ and I have edited the question as well.

Comment: Neither edit nor comment changes the fact that $\,\dfrac{3}{2} = 1.5 \not\gt 2 = \dfrac{3-1}{2-1}\,$. So, again, what exactly is it that you want to prove?

Comment: Yes,now check the edit.

Comment: After the edit, the inequality will hold if $\,a\gt b\gt x\gt 0\,$. Just $\,a\gt b\,$ is not enough for it to hold, try for example $\,a=4, b=2, x=3\,$.

Comment: Yes, I also think that means there is not enough criteria given for the statement to hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $c,d,e,f$ are all $> 0$, then 
$\frac{c}{d} > \frac{e}{f} \iff (cf > de).$

Therefore 
$a > b > 0$ and $(a-x) > (b-x) > 0$ implies that
$\frac{a}{b} < \frac{a-x}{b-x}$.

This is because $(-ax) < (-bx) \implies (ab - ax) < (ab - bx).$

---

Assume that $a > b > 0$, and $(0 > [b-x])$.

If $([a-x] > 0)$ then $\frac{a-x}{b-x}$ is a negative number, and so $\frac{a}{b} > 0 > \frac{a-x}{b-x}.$

---

If $([a-x] < 0$ then $\frac{a-x}{b-x} = \frac{x-a}{x-b}$, where $(x-b) > (x - a) > 0.$

This allows $\frac{a}{b}$ to be compared against $\frac{x-a}{x-b}$ 
by comparing $(ax - ab)$ against $(bx - ab).$

Since $a > b,$ you have that $(ax - ab) > (bx - ab),$ 
and so, in this situation, $\frac{a}{b} > \frac{x - a}{x - b}.$

**Edit**
Shortcut to the last situation is to realize that since $a > b$, $(x - b) > (x - a).$

Therefore, in the last situation, you have that $\frac{a}{b} > 1 > \frac{x-a}{x - b} > 0.$

Comment: So does it means that it depends on the condition, right?

Comment: @MohdSaad Yes, that's it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Let $0<b<a$.  Define for $x\neq b$ the function
$$f(x)=\frac{a}{b}-\frac{a-x}{b-x}.$$
We have $f(x)=0\iff x =0$.
As $f$ is continuous it may change sign at its zeroes or where it's undefined, that is in $x=0$ or $x=b$.  We easily find that $f$ is negative, which means that
$$\frac{a}{b}<\frac{a-x}{b-x},$$
iff $0<x<b$.